# How to generate reports covering Maven dependencies in a Java project using JaCoCo or any other tool?

Tags: java, jacoco

My project uses two other libraries that are added to it as Maven dependencies. When I generate a coverage report for the project using the command prompt, it generates the `jacoco.exec` file and I can use it to see the coverage report in the IDE.

But it doesn't give me coverage over the dependencies used.

I have seen in the Eclipse plugin for JaCoCo where it gives the opportunity to configure coverage and select specific jars being used in the project to be included in the coverage report.

How can I to the same in the case of command line based execution?

Answer (score 0):

> My project use two other libraries which are added to it as a maven dependency.

If those libraries are other modules of the same Maven build, then please have a look at [`report-aggregate` goal](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/report-aggregate-mojo.html) of JaCoCo Maven Plugin.

> I have seen in eclipse plugin for JaCoCo where it gives opportunity to configure coverage and select specific jars being used in the project to be included in coverage report. But how to do same in the case of command line based execution?

In JaCoCo 0.7.9 there are [JaCoCo Ant Tasks](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html), and in 0.8.0 there will be [JaCoCo Command Line Interface](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/cli.html) - both provide more freedom than JaCoCo Maven Plugin in specification of what should be included into report, in particular can be used for arbitrary (e.g. third-party) JAR files. Ant Tasks can be executed from within Maven build using [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/).

And there is [JaCoCo APIs](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/api/index.html) with [examples](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/api.html) (in particular `ReportGenerator.java`) that can be used to build you own report generators, other integrations. Mentioned by you Eclipse plugin that is based on JaCoCo - is [Eclipse EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/). And it uses exactly these APIs for integration into Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Use Codehaus plugin for better result which generates class wise coverage report. you can generate html as well as xml report.

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <formats>
            <format>html</format>
            <format>xml</format>
          </formats>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.5.5.201112152213</version>
  <configuration>
     <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
     <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
     <execution>
         <excludes>
            <exclude>**/*Config.*</exclude>
            <exclude>**/*Dev.*</exclude>
     </excludes>
  </execution>
  <execution>
        <id>jacoco-site</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
           <goal>report</goal>
       </goals>
     </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

You can also provide in  tag to exclude the classes for code coverage and similarly for  tag for including the classes